# Inconvenientes para instalar psycopg2 en windows

Tags: python, django

estoy intentando generar un entorno de trabajo para un proyecto en Django 2.2.6 y me gustaría utilizar Postgresql para este proyecto.

Al momento de instalarlo me aparece este error:

```
    (prueba1) C:\Users\Statick\Documents\proyectos\entornos\prueba1>pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\statick\documents\proyectos\entornos\prueba1\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Statick\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gxdulf5d\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Statick\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gxdulf5d\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Statick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxdulf5d\psycopg2\pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

He leido la documentación oficial e intente compilarlo a traves de los comandos.

```
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Sin embargo tampoco tuve éxito.

Pd: estoy instalando en un entorno virtual con python 3.8

Comment: Tienes postgresql instalado?

Answer (score 0):

Fundamento: `pg_config` es la utilidad de configuración proporcionada por `PostgreSQL`. Esta utilidad es utilizada por varias aplicaciones.

Solución:

1. Instala `PostgreSQL`.
2. Establecer el PATH. Propiedades del sistema> Avanzado

   PATH: `C:\Archivos de programa (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\`;

A partir de este momento, cualquier aplicación que requiera `pg_config` puede encontrarla aquí.

pd: Solución obtenida de [pregunta relacionada de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717436/pg-config-executable-not-found-when-using-pgxnclient-on-windows-7-x64).